# Form Design with bootstrap - Align Text boxes and text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

As shown in the image above, I want to move the textbox up to align with TextArea. Is there any Bootstrap class I can apply? I'm using boostrap 3.3.6

**HTML**

```
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row top-buffer">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Quote Date:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtReference" class="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Quote Prepared By:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         <div class="row top-buffer">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Reseller:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                                Notes:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" class="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="252px" Width="414px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                        <div class="row top-buffer">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Reseller Contact:
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" class="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You must divide your form in two columns. In bootstrap,  `col-md-6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want, a cleaner and responsive design. Your goal here is to have to col-md-6 columns, since you are splitting content into two columns:

Resize your browser and see result:
https://jsfiddle.net/L4LtoLsz/

```
<div class="panel-body">
<form class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row top-buffer">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quote Date:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Quote Date">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Reseller</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail2" placeholder="Reseller">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Reseller Contact:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Reseller Contact">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row top-buffer">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail5" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quote Prepared By:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail5" placeholder="Quote Prepared By">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tarea" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Notes:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <textarea id="tarea" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: No prob, i also suggest u check form examples on bootstrap website, to make design cleaner u can remove labels alltogether, leaving only placeholders, depending on your application.