# How to split a form into two columns?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a basic form which passes input to a PHP script. I'd like to split the form up so that the second sub-entry (Person 2) sits in a column to the right of the first (Person 1), rather than directly below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">    
    <form class="form-validation" method="post" action="script.php">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
       <h2>Person 1:</h2>
       <br>
       <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
          <label>
          <span>Name</span>
          <input name="field1" type="text">
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
          <label>
          <span>Age</span>
          <input name="field2" type="text">
          </label>
       </div>
       <div class="main-content">
          <h2>Person 2:</h2>
          <br>
          <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
             <label>
             <span>Name</span>
             <input name="field3" type="text">
             </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
             <label>
             <span>Age</span>
             <input name="field4" type="text">
             </label>
          </div>
    </form>
    <div>
    <button name="submit">Submit form</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS that you have tried?

Comment: Check out my answer here with bootstrap enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737985/form-design-with-bootstrap-align-text-boxes-and-text-areas/35738229#35738229  Working example, resize your browser and see result: https://jsfiddle.net/L4LtoLsz/

Comment: Select one of the answers as the top one, if either worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap both entries in a div with the same class (e.g. "sub-entry") and float them left with a width of 50%:

```css
.sub-entry {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-validation" method="post" action="script.php">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <div class="sub-entry">
        <h2>Person 1:</h2>
        <br>
        <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
            <label>
                <span>Name</span>
                <input name="field1" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
            <label>
                <span>Age</span>
                <input name="field2" type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-entry">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Person 2:</h2>
            <br>
            <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Name</span>
                    <input name="field3" type="text">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Age</span>
                    <input name="field4" type="text">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="button">
    <button name="submit">Submit both forms</button>
</div>
```

Notice I also gave the div containing the button a class button and styled it to the center of the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can try CSS [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
form { display: flex; }
```

```html
<form class="form-validation" method="post" action="script.php">

  <div class="person-1">
    <h2>Person 1:</h2>
    <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
      <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input name="field1" type="text">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
      <label>
        <span>Age</span>
        <input name="field2" type="text">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end .person-1 -->
  
  <div class="main-content person-2">
    <h2>Person 2:</h2>
    <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
      <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input name="field3" type="text">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row form-input-name-row">
      <label>
        <span>Age</span>
        <input name="field4" type="text">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end .person-2 -->
  
</form>

<div><button name="submit">Submit form</button></div>
```

*Benefits of flexbox:*

1. minimal code; very efficient
2. [centering, both vertically and horizontally, is simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276)
3. [equal height columns are simple and easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33815389/3597276)
4. [multiple options for aligning flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
5. it's responsive
6. unlike floats and tables, which offer limited layout capacity because they were never intended for building layouts, flexbox is a modern (CSS3) technique with a broad range of options.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More browser compatibility details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*